# (AS3) TypeError: Error #1009 when trying to call a function on every frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

First off, let me start by saying that I'm really new to ActionScript 3.
I have a function that needs to be called on every frame. So I put the function into the frame, then I made a movie clip, and gave it the instance name of 'StageFrame'

This is my code:

```
const NUM_BALL:int = 24;
var loadingBall:Vector.<Shape> = new Vector.<Shape (NUM_BALL);
var timeStep:int = 0;
const BALL_HEIGHT:int = 40;

    function animateBalls(e:Event):void
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < NUM_BALL; i++ )
        {
        loadingBall[i].graphics.clear();
        loadingBall[i].graphics.beginFill(0x0B5F95);
        loadingBall[i].graphics.drawCircle(455+5*i,getY(i,timeStep),2);
    }
    timeStep++;
}

function getY(i:int, t:int):int
{
    return 260 + BALL_HEIGHT/2 * (1 + Math.sin((timeStep * (i/500 + 0.02)) % 2*Math.PI));
}

StageFrame.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateBalls);
```

When I run it, I get this error:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/animateBalls()

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you will get the `Error #1009` error because you have not created your `Shape`s before animate it into your `animateBalls()` function.

So you can do like this :

```
var loadingBall:Vector.<Shape>  = new Vector.<Shape> ();

// create your Shape objects and add it to your stageFrame MovieClip
for (var i:int = 0; i < NUM_BALL; i++)
{
    var shape:Shape = new Shape();

    // add your shape to your loadingBall Vector
    loadingBall.push(shape);

    // add your shape to your stageFrame
    stageFrame.addChild(shape);     
    // it's better to start with a lowercase letter for an object name, uppercase letter is for Class names
} 

function animateBalls(e:Event):void 
{
    var shape:Shape;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < loadingBall.length; i++)
        shape = loadingBall[i];
        shape.graphics.clear();
        shape.graphics.beginFill(0x0B5F95);
        shape.graphics.drawCircle(455 + (5*i), getY(i, timeStep), 2);
    }
    timeStep++;

}
```

Hope that can help.